# Camera api preview not showing

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement my own camera without using the camera intent.

When I try to setPreviewSize() from the camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes() highest resolution it doesn't display the preview on some devices. It work for the majority but not all...

This is my res supported list

SIZE 1280     960
SIZE 1280     720
SIZE 800     480
SIZE 720     720
SIZE 720     480
SIZE 640     480
SIZE 352     288
SIZE 320     240
SIZE 176     144

Not working for 1280 * 960 but ok for 1280 * 720 for this specific device. Is it kind of magical or something :-/

Tcs for help !

Comment: Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note the official recommendation on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html:

```
This class was deprecated in API level 21.
We recommend using the new android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications.
```

Now, could you please be more specific on which devices doesn't it work? It seems like it is not your fault since some devices simply just won't support every resolution.

Comment: Txs for your response but sorry I will not skip 60% of my users using camera v2. I know that this class I deprecated :).

Comment: And how the device cannot support the size given on getSupportedPreviewSizes() :-/

Comment: Sorry to hear that Hiromi but you were not specific on which device/sdk gave you those results.